# Python: pass by reference

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the behaviour demonstrated below please. Suppose we have the simple class

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self._df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], columns=['c1'], index=['r1', 'r2', 'r3'])

    @property
    def df(self):
        return self._df

    def summary(self):
        df2 = self.df
        df2['c2'] = pd.Series([4,5,6], index=df2.index)
        return df2
```

and we make an instance `a`:

```
a = A()
```

Then `a.df` returns

```
    c1
r1  1
r2  2
r3  3
```

Calling the `summary` method

```
s = a.summary()
s
```

returns

```
    c1  c2
r1  1   4
r2  2   5
r3  3   6
```

which is fine so far. However the `df` property (and the underlying attribute) of object `a` have now been changed too.

```
a.df

    c1  c2
r1  1   4
r2  2   5
r3  3   6
```

I understand in broad lines that it has to do with the much-discussed pass by reference design of Python and I suspect the key here is the line `df2=self.df` in the `summary` method. Hence `df2` is actually a reference pointing to the same memory location as `self.df`. Therefore when we modify the object labeled as `df2` (by adding one more column in this example) we will be able to see the modified object by calling either `df2` or `self.df` because they both point to the same thing.

Is this a fair understanding please? What are the best practices If we wanted to decouple the two? Edit `df2` without affecting `df`. Make an explicit copy by `df2 = self.df.copy()` or something else?

Comment: Yes.  Create a copy.

Comment: "pass by reference" - Python does not use pass by reference. It uses a parameter passing model that unfortunately has no well-accepted name, despite its wide use in modern programming languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `df2 = self.df.copy()` would resolve your problem, but this has nothing to do with *pass by value* or *pass by reference* which refer to arguments in function calls, and neither of which accurately describes Python's function-call semantics anyway.

For your situation, as well as for parameters in function calls, the easiest mental picture is Brett Cannon's idea of *sticky labels*.  All the names, e.g. so-called *variable names*, are sticky labels that refer to an actual object.  So you can create as many sticky labels as you like:

```
def f():
    pass

g = h = k = m = f  # You created 4 new sticky labels that refer to a single function

class A():
    pass

g = h = k = m = A  # Reusing same 4 labels, all refer to one class

a = ()
g = h = k = m = a  # Reusing same 4 labels, all refer to one instance
```

Reassigning a label (name) to a different object, simply means that the previous object loses a reference.  When an object has no more reference, it gets deleted.  In the example above, I created a bunch of references to an instance of the class `A`.  Using the `del` keyword you can remove *names* (i.e. *sticky labels*), but the underlying object only gets deleted when there are no more references to it.

```
del h
del k
del m
del a

# At this point, there is still one active reference to the instance
# that we first created when we assigned it to name "a".

del g

# Now we have removed all references to that instance, so it gets deleted.
```

Comment: Thanks, thats helpful indeed, Does it happen to have a link/pointer to Brett's sticky labels idea? I cant find it.

Comment: I can't seem to find it now! Sorry about that.  I may have misattributed the origin.  See [this post](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/edu-sig/2008-May/008531.html) on the Python edu-sig mailing list.